# WCF Configuration enhancement

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

WCF Configuration Enhancement

**Background:**

In `app.config` or `web.config` one may define a config entry in:

```
<appSettings>...</appSettings>
```

like so:

```
<add key="MyKey" value="%SomeEnvironmentVariable%"/>
```

Thereafter in order to retrieve the value associated with `MyKey` one may employ the following two lines of code:

```
string raw = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[“MyKey”];

string cooked = (raw == null) ? null : Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(raw);
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to do the same with the WCF service configuration, for example:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    . . .
    <services>
        <service name="..." ...>
          . . .
            <endpoint 
                address="%MyEndPointAddress%" ... />
            . . .
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any knowledge will be highly appreciated.

--Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change endpoint address you will need to know EndPointName and ContractName. This values are found in your config file inside WCF configuration. Then you can use following code:

```
    void SetNewEndpointAddress(string endpointName, string contractName, string newValue)
    {
        bool settingsFound = false;
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ClientSection section = config.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement ep in section.Endpoints)
        {
            if (ep.Name == endpointName && ep.Contract == contractName)
            {
                settingsFound = true;
                ep.Address = new Uri(newValue);
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            }
        }
        if (!settingsFound)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Settings for Endpoint '{0}' and Contract '{1}' was not found!", endpointName, contractName));
        }
    }
```

Happy coding!